# Python- How to flush the log? (django)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-logging, django-nonrel

I'm working with Django-nonrel on Google App Engine, which forces me to use `logging.debug()` instead of `print()`.

The "logging" module is provided by Django, but I'm having a rough time using it instead of `print()`.

For example, if I need to verify the content held in the variable x, I will put
`logging.debug('x is: %s' % x)`. But if the program crashes soon after (without flushing the stream), then it never gets printed.

So for debugging, I need `debug()` to be flushed before the program exits on error, and this is not happening.

Comment: not an answer to your question but why would you use `print` anyway?!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "flushing" the log?

Comment: Hopefully the example listed helps in understanding.

Comment: I'd try something like the [AdminEmailHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler) logging handler for specific cases such as your example.
A database logging handler would be the better choice, not sure if there's a free [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/) alternative out there.

Comment: Might not be the right one, but this works for me.Hope this helps someone.  I tried using flush() method, but did not work. As I exit my application using sys.exit(..), I have created a wrapper method(`exit()`) around it...which waited for `1` second(`time.sleep(1)`) before exiting the Application.  I am also catching any unexpected error and calling `exit()` method. This timeout seems to flushout any pending log messages

Answer (score 35):

I think this may work for you, assuming you're only using one(or default) handler:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()
>>> logging.debug('wat wat')
>>> logger.handlers[0].flush()
```

It's kind of frowned upon in the documentation, though.

> Application code should not directly instantiate and use instances of Handler. Instead, the Handler class is a base class that defines the interface that all handlers should have and establishes some default behavior that child classes can use (or override).
>   http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handler-basic

And it could be a performance drain, but if you're really stuck, this may help with your debugging.

Comment: Uh, how awre people supposed to flush their logs if the only way is through a handler that you're not supposed to access? That sounds broken.

Comment: No, that is not at all what the documentation says. The quote above means that you should only instantiate and use *subclasses* of Handler, instead of Handler directly. Your code only uses whatever handler classes are already instantiated by someone else, so there is no problem.

Comment: Very helpful indeed; I still find it extremely strange that I am not able to tell the stupid logger in its config that it always flush; but that my client code has to enforce that.

Comment: It returns "out of range". I initialized the logger using a .ini file with two handlers. logging.hasHandlers() returns true.

logger.handlers[0].flush()
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 27):

If the use case is that you have a python program that should flush its logs when exiting, use [`logging.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.shutdown).

From the python documentation:

> logging.shutdown()
>
> Informs the logging system to perform an orderly
> shutdown by flushing and closing all handlers. This should be called
> at application exit and no further use of the logging system should be
> made after this call. [...]

Answer (score 7):

Django logging relies on the standard python logging module.

This module has a module-level method: `logging.shutdown()` which flushes all of the handlers and shuts down the logging system (i.e. logging can not longer be used after it is called)

Inspecting the code of this function shows that currently (python 2.7) the logging module holds a list of weak references to all handlers in a module-level variable called _handlerList so all of the handlers can be flushed by doing something like

```
[h_weak_ref().flush() for h_weak_ref in logging._handlerList]
```

because this solution uses the internals of the module @Mikes solution above is better, but it relies on having access to a logger, it can be generalized as follows:

```
 [h.flush() for h in my_logger.handlerList]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python3.8:

`logging.shutdown( )`

Check: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logging.shutdown

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the logger is not logging (seemingly not flushing) because an exception is being raised in a thread. The thread will need to catch its own exceptions and log them itself.

You cannot rely on a main thread to catch and log thread exceptions.

For example, a timer that runs a function periodically will have this behavior and that function will need to catch and log its exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I wanted my `log.info` to be flushed to the `std:out`. Turns out I just had to add a stream handler to stdout and it does the job.

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)).
```

Also, add the right level for logging but that's obvious.

Answer (score -3):

a simple function that always working for register you debug messsages while programming. dont use it for production, since it will not rotate:

```
def make_log(message):
    import datetime
    with open('mylogfile.log','a') as f:
        f.write(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} {message}\n")
```

then use as

```
make_log('my message to register')
```

when to put on production, just comment the last 2 lines

```
def make_log(message):
    import datetime
    #with open('mylogfile.log','a') as f:
    #    f.write(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} {message}\n")
```

Comment: implementing some trivial logger does not solve the problem. There is a good reason, why sophisticated loggers are available and with with implementation you will (sooner or later) encounter most of them the hard way. Some reasons: Performance, log levels,